# Simple form data not working

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post

I'm trying to upload an image and send it over to a server using a very basic form in HTML. Here is my code:

```
        <form action="/api/addCategory" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="test">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

However when I click the button nothing happens (the server doesn't get any requests). The strange thing is I'm using an almost identical version of this code somewhere else in my project and it's working completely fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript which could be intercepting submits on the form? What does the network tab of the inspector say? And the console?

Comment: @jcaron I don't have any js files that intercept submits. Network tab doesn't change when I click the button and the console is completely empty.

Comment: Does the browser actually load the addCategory page, or when clicking submit just it just sit there?

Comment: Is the code above an actual cut and paste? If not, you might have a typo somewhere in the actual code maybe? Try adding a submit event handler to see if it’s correctly triggered.

Comment: @j08691 Browser doesn't load anything. Nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Comment: @jcaron It is actual copy/paste. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you see any change of the button when you click on it? Just trying to make sure you don’t have something “over” the button preventing clicks, or a pointer-events: none in your CSS for instance.

Comment: @jcaron The button is animated normally.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or something equivalent which illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ! Use any server side language like php.

```
<form action="/api/addCategory" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="test">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input class="fileattach" type="file" placeholder="upload" name="attachment" required><br></input>
</form>
```